# My iframe is blank

Tags: html, css, iframe, tumblr

I've been trying to use an iframe as a hero header on my tumblr, it is appearing but blank...

Here is the line of code I've injected in the tumblr theme html editor :

```
<iframe frameborder="0" src="http://drowningdoodles.olympe.in/index.html" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
```

The index itself works fine but not in my iframe, is it possible that an iframe can't show scripts ? (like the one on my index) or are my links broken (I've checked and saw now muslin's though)

Here is the code of my index :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1,IE=edge" />
<title>DD - frontpage</title>
<style>
    html {
        height:100%;
    }
    body {
        margin:0;
        height:100%;
    }
</style>
<!-- copy these lines to your document head: -->

<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, width=320" />

<style>

body {
height: 100%;
background: linear-gradient(#03c3eb 50%, #0096ba 50%);
}

.social-button {
transition: all 0.1s ease-out 0s;
}

</style>


<!-- end copy -->
</head>
<body>
<!-- copy these lines to your document: -->

<div id="ddfrontpage_hype_container" style="margin:auto;position:relative;width:100%;height:100%;overflow:hidden;" aria-live="polite">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://drowningdoodles.olympe.in/DD%20-%20frontpage.hyperesources/ddfrontpage_hype_generated_script.js?28842"></script>
</div>

<!-- end copy -->



<!-- text content for search engines: -->

<div style="display:none">

    <div></div>

</div>

<!-- end text content: -->
```

Comment: Have you checked the console for any errors?

Comment: ok this this is very funny... the iframe work perfectly but not in the editor... so everything is fine after all wow !

thx i discovered that trying to look into the console :)

Comment: In console, if a put in jsfiddle, I obtain an error: it seems the loading of the content has been blocked (check here: https://jsfiddle.net/c02zmft4/). Your code has nothing wrong: http://jsfiddle.net/zwqrtLrf/

Comment: yes, i fact i think the editor is blocking it but my iframe works fine on the tumblr page :) check it there http://drowningdoodles.tumblr.com/

Comment: You can only serve content in jsfiddle via https, not http. So it's not a good testing ground for any content which is http only (fortunately tumblr content can be served via https).